# Error Chaincode Instantiate Hyperledger (with node)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm learning how to develop chaincodes and I'm trying to modify the chaincode from fabcar tutorial to work with collections. I'm trying to use the node version of the chaincode.

I set up a **config.json** file to hold the collection configuration. I made a simple one (basically a copy from marbles tutorial):

```
[
  {
       "name": "car",
       "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member')",
       "requiredPeerCount": 0,
       "maxPeerCount": 3,
       "blockToLive":1000000
  },
  {
       "name": "privateCar",
       "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member')",
       "requiredPeerCount": 0,
       "maxPeerCount": 3,
       "blockToLive":1000000
  }
]
```

and I updated the file **startFabric.sh** to pass the collections-config flag like:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel - -n fabhealth -l "$LANGUAGE"  -v 1.0  -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')" --collections-config $CC_SRC_PATH/config_old.json
```

But when I try to instantiate the chaincode, I'm receiving this error:

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err Proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg invalid number of arguments to lscc: 7

I tryed to update the **configtx.yaml** as some other tutorials suggested, to update the Cappabilities.Application section but it didn't work.

I would like to know if I am missing something in order to instantiate the chaincode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate the hellp for the other comments. In fact, I updated congigtx.yaml and this is really required. What I was missing is that I need to run **configtxgen** command in order to make the updates visible when setting up the network again.

After doing that, I was able to use private data collections.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming due to invalid arguments to lscc from below code

```
// the maximum number of arguments depends on the capability of the channel
if (!ac.Capabilities().PrivateChannelData() && len(args) > 6) ||
    (ac.Capabilities().PrivateChannelData() && len(args) > 7) {
    return shim.Error(InvalidArgsLenErr(len(args)).Error())
}
```

Try changing capabilities in your **configtx.yaml** and you don't have to pass **--collections-config** argument.

Comment: Hey have you worked it out. I have changed capabilities in configtx.yaml. It is still giving same error

Comment: As I commented in my asnwer, uodating configtx is really required but is also needed to run configtxgen in order to make the update available for the network.